# java , volatile static and synchronized - null exception in threa

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

I defined a public volatile LinkedList to be shared with some threads, and I synchronize it within main() which is static...
so  I get a compile error : " cannot make a reference to a non static field"

If I modify the definition to be public volatile static LinkedList, then I get an exception :

```
 Exception in thread "filteringThread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.swimtechtest.swimmerbench.FilteringThread.run(FilteringThread.java:39)
```

here is part of my code

```
public class SwimmerBench{
    ...
    public volatile LinkedList<InterpolatedEvent> samplings = new LinkedList<InterpolatedEvent>();
    ...
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
       ...
       InterpolatedEvent event = createInterpolatedEvent(fields);
   synchronized(samplings){
        samplings.add(event);
    samplings.notifyAll();
   }
       ...
    }
}

  ======

public class FilteringThread extends Thread {

    LinkedList<InterpolatedEvent> samplings;
       public void run() {

   System.out.println("Running " +  threadName );

  while(running ) {
      try {
        synchronized(samplings) { // <=  exception error line 39
            InterpolatedEvent event = samplings.getLast();
            samplings.notifyAll();
       }
  }
}
```

Comment: `samplings` must be null in your thread.  Where do you set it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I defined a public volatile LinkedList to be shared with some threads,
>   and I synchronize it within main() which is static... so I get a
>   compile error : " cannot make a reference to a non static field"

It's not related to volatile or synchronization, it's because you are accessing instance variable `samplings` in static `main()` method.

> If I modify the definition to be public volatile static LinkedList,
>   then I get an exception :
>
> ```
>  Exception in thread "filteringThread" java.lang.NullPointerException
> at com.swimtechtest.swimmerbench.FilteringThread.run(FilteringThread.java:39)
> ```

This is because, your instance variable `samplings` in `FilteringThread` is never assigned to an object of type `List`. It's assigned by default null